# Vertical align : baseline doesnt work in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, alignment, baseline

I have this really silly question to be honest.
Anyways here goes. 
Ive been trying to use the vertical align: baseline; which is working in itself. The problem is that it works in IE and Firefox. My problem is that for some wierd reason it doesnt work in Chrome. 
a screenshot of the problem in chrome
http://img576.imageshack.us/img576/8976/chromem.png

And this is how its supposed to look like ( There is a 14px padding else it would be at the very top)
http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/140/firefoxi.png
it looks the same in IE as in firefox.

Im not using a table to my images and texts (Just pointing out)
I hope that someone can help me because this has been giving me headaches for 2 days now almost :(

Comment: Code snippet please. Preferably in http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the background div to `display: table` and each of it's children to `display: table-cell`, it should work.

```
#outer_div
{
    display: table; /* display: inline-table; works as well */
}

#outer_div div
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```